# prestashop 1.4 to 1.6 image missing issue

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've upgraded a Prestashop site manually from 1.4 to 1.6.I can get the category images to appear but not the product images.
My product path on the old 1.4 site takes the following route

.../img/p/11-638-home.jpg

but version 1.6 is asking for

Original image is missing or empty (/.../.../../img/p/1/1.jpg) for product ID 11,when click regenerate thumbnails image

How do I change/recreate the url structure to match? I don't think I can create these directories manually, there's too many products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Backup Your Entire code.Then follow step by step

**Step 1 :** When I try moving the images I get the following error.

Error: Your server configuration is not compatible with the new image system. No images were moved.

**Step 2 :** First disable friendly URL in SEO(backend) then Go to ../controllers/admin/AdminImagesController.php file and line no around 68

change

```
// No need to display the old image system migration tool except if product images are in _PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_
    $this->display_move = false;
```

to

```
$this->display_move = true;
```

**Step 3 :** Click Move images.

**Step 4 :** Finally click REGENERATE THUMBNAILS(If you need Erase previous images -- NO)

It will take several minutes.After finishing,refresh your site you got images in the sites.

Thanks